# Can i shim a function without the need for a file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using requirejs 2. I have a function that is defined in the main html template (using templated data), and I would like to be sure that this function is called as a dependency of the other modules.

One obvious choice was to declare a shim:

```
     shim: {
        initialization: {
            exports: "initialization",
            init: function () {
                window.apidata = {
                    base_url: "{{base_url}}",
                    prefix: "{{prefix}}",
                    {% if user %}
                    user: "{{user.name}}",
                    {% endif %}
                };
                return window.apidata;
            }
        }
```

and then put a "initialization" entry in the define() of my dependent module. However, require keeps demanding a "initialization.js" file, which I don't have. I also tried to have the function as exports, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same functionality as the one you'd get from a fileless `shim` by defining a named module:

```
define("initialization", function () {
  window.apidata = {
    base_url: "{{base_url}}",
    prefix: "{{prefix}}",
    {% if user %}
    user: "{{user.name}}",
    {% endif %}
  };
  return window.apidata;
});
```

So long as the code above is executed *before* any code that requires `initialization`, RequireJS will not go to the network to resolve `initialization` but will know it is already defined.

Once, way back when, I tried to see if I could create a fileless `shim` but I did not find a way to do that.